# substring windows command line

Tags: command-line, cmd

I tried to get the substring from each line of a text file based on fixed position in the file. I would like to achieve that using command lines.

My file look like this:

```
45testing45
46testing46
47testing47
48testing48
49testing49
50testing50
51testing51
52testing52
53testing53
```

I tried the following command line:

```
For -F %i in (inputFile.txt) do (SET _line=%i SET _chars=%_line:~10,2% @echo _chars > outputFile.txt)
```

But the result is that the outputFile.txt is created but empty and when I hit SET in the command prompt, I see the _line variable as such _line=53testing53 SET _chars=%_line:~10,2% @echo _chars > outputFile.txt)
I do not get why, I suppose I miss a delimiter in the DO part so that I can separate the different SET command.

Could you please help me get the last 2 digits of my file in a new output file? I have downloaded Cygwin so am open to Unix command as well but I do not understand how to extract a fixed length substring of each line of a file using sed or awk.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean `for /F` but not `for -F`...

Comment: Yes sorry typo I meant /F

Comment: You need to put `&` between multiple commands in a single line...

Answer (score 2):

This may work for you:

```dos
(For /F %A In (inputFile.txt) Do @Set "_=%A"&Call Echo ^%_:~-2^%)>outputFile.txt
```

Comment: @aschipfl, it reads exactly as it should, I have escaped each of the percent characters, **`%`**, enclosing the variable named **`_`** with carets, **`^`**. _Unlike most of my code, this one was actually tested, on Windows Vista!_

Comment: I can confirm it works also on Windows 7; anyway, this is actually not escaping, because `%` signs are recognised *before* `^`; seems that you are lucky, because the `~-2^` is invalid sub-string expansion syntax and is therefore simply not expanded (but is not a fatal error that aborts execution); so the second parsing phase receives the string without `^`, which is valid syntax...

Comment: @aschipfl, I used the term escaping, simply for easy understanding, I really didn't want to explain further. I'm intrigued however as to why `%_:~-2%` is invalid syntax though, it is specifically expanding to the last two characters, a similar example `%_test:~-7%` is given [here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html). e.g. `SET _test=123456789abcdef0` followed by `::Extract only the last 7 characters` and `SET _result=%_test:~-7%` with `ECHO %_result%          =abcdef0`.

Comment: `%_:~-2^%` is not valid syntax (note the caret), that's why it's not expanded in the first phase; the second phase receives the string without the `^`, so it's valid then... anyway, it works...

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of typos, and I put it into a script.

```
For /F %%i in (inputFile.txt) do (CALL :DisplaySubString %%i)
GOTO :EOF

:DisplaySubString
SET _line=%1 
SET _chars=%_line:~9,2% 
@echo %_chars% >> outfile.txt
```

One problem is that you're trying to process variables within `()`. You would need to use DelayedExpansion to do that.

To get around that, I made a "subroutine" in the .cmd file called `:DisplaySubString`.

Your indexing was off by one, `10` -> `9`.

`@echo %_chars%` was missing the `%`

You have to use `>>` instead of `>` to append to the file as you go.

Comment: Mike, the question example and tags are for the command line in cmd.exe and you've provided Windows batch script answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you do not really need Cygwin in Windows if you wanna solve this quest with sed ([see this repo for the details](https://github.com/mbuilov/sed-windows)). After downloading and placing sed's binary in the PATH variable you can type in the command prompt next command:

```
sed -r "s/.*([0-9]{2})/\1/" input.txt > output.txt
```

and it'll be done. You can find online sed's manual page [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed).
Pure cmd script:

```
@echo off
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "f=C:\files\input.txt"
    >C:\files\output.txt (for /f %%i in (%f%) do (
      set "l=%%i"
      echo !l:~-2!
    ))
  endlocal
exit /b
```