# How to get lines that start with specific word in cmd from a text file?

Tags: cmd, ping

I was trying to simulate real network with packet tracer. So I get the website URLs in a specific domain and tided them in an ASCII file with file name `WebSites-DB` line by line like this:

```
www.google.com
stackoverflow.com
```

Then I used the command `ping` to get their IP addresses:

```
FOR /F "eol=#" %i in (WebSites-DB) do ping %1 -n 1 -w 1 1>> Ips.txt
```

But `ping` output multiple lines:

```
Pinging www.google.com [8.8.8.8] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 185.216.132.250:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss),
```

I want only the websites name `www.google.com` and its IP address `8.8.8.8`.

How to get just the data of interest?

Comment: The `ping` tool does not "simulate real network traffic" because it sends out IGMP packets that network equipment like routers and firewalls treat differently to normal web HTTPS/TCP packets.

Comment: I know....I am just using it to get the ips....

Comment: To resolve hostnames you should use `dig` or `nslookup` instead of `ping`.

Answer (score 0):

use this line:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2,3 delims= " %i in (`find "Pinging" Ips.txt`) do @Set "_=%j"&Call Echo %i ^%_:~1,-1^%
```

it will give result such like:

```
www.goog.com 8.8.8.8
```

More info:
[substring windows command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50882302/substring-windows-command-line)